# Selenium iframe selection issue

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing our website login sequence with selenium.  When I click login it loads an iframe, and the iframe id value changes each time it is loaded.  So the test case fails in selenium.

What is the the command to read only the dynamic part of the iframe and locate it during the test run?

Comment: Care to show us the HTML of the IFrame or do we need to play a guessing game? Show us two copies of it - so we can see what *exactly* is 'dynamic' and what *exactly* changes between runs.

Answer (score 0):

try this for capturing the popup,

```
String parentWindowHandle = browser.getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
  WebDriver popup = null;
  Iterator<String> windowIterator = browser.getWindowHandles();
  while(windowIterator.hasNext()) { 
    String windowHandle = windowIterator.next(); 
    popup = browser.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
   }
```

Hope it will helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameIndex to switch iframes.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

or use xpath

```
driver.switchTo().frame(webElement)
```

Or share Html Code so we can give a better solution.